# Как правильно выйти с анонимного делегата

Tags: c#

```
public override async Task<DamageResult> TakeDamage(CharacterEntity target)
{
    if (target == null)
        return DamageResult.DamageFail;

    if (target.IsDead)
        return DamageResult.DamageFail;

    Formulas.CalculateTakeDamage(CharacterStats, target.CharacterStats);
    EventsHandler.ValidDeathTarget(target, async () =>
    {
        await target.BroadcastPacketAsync(CharacterDeath.ToPacket());
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    });

    // here

    StatusUpdate status = new StatusUpdate();
    status.AddAttribute(StatusUpdate.CurrentHealth, target.CharacterStats.CurrentHealth);
    status.AddAttribute(StatusUpdate.MaxHealth, target.CharacterStats.BaseHealth);

    await target.BroadcastPacketAsync(StatusUpdate.ToPacket(status, target), excludeYourself: false);

    return DamageResult.DamageNormal;
}
```

Если `EventsHandler.ValidDeathTarget` вернет `true`, выполняется синхронный анонимный делегат. Программа дальше пойдет работать? И как с этого делегата полностью завершить работу метода?

Comment: Ну проверяйте, что он возвращает. Вы же не проверяете. Или я не понял контекст. Ещё странно, что метод `Formulas.CalculateTakeDamage` ничего не возвращает. Он меняет внутреннее состояние или что он делает? Странный в общем код. И "выполняется синхронный анонимный делегат" - это о чём, где тут этот делегат?

Comment: Task.Delay для синхронизации? Для выхода из глубины попробуйте использовать throw

Comment: Делегат это же метод, чтобы он завершился, надо либо чтобы выполнился весь код, либо return вызвать, больше никак.